# How to change things in lists

Tags: python

```
import random
word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()

display = []
chosen_word_length = len(chosen_word)
for length in range(chosen_word_length):
  display.append("_")
print(display)
```

I am trying to make a hangman game but the thing I'm struggling on is when the player guesses a letter that is in the word how to I insert that letter in the correct place in "display".

I'm really struggling on this and help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose implementing a set that stores all letters which are already know.

Your diplaying would then look like this:

```
# known_letters is a set holding all letters that player guessed
display = ["_"] * len(chosen_word)
for i in range (len(chosen_word)):
   if chosen_word[i] in known_letters:
      display[i] = chosen_word[i]

print(display)
```

Comment: If you've got to eventually check whether letters match at a all positions, why would you bother checking the entire word using `in`?

Comment: What do you mean with that? Every letter is checked individually. One could also check positions only when it is _ so far. But that makes is more complicated and not better.

Answer (score 0):

The word is "baboon" and you have

```py
display = ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
```

And want to make it

```py
display = ['b', '_', 'b', '_', '_', '_']
```

---

You could loop over "baboon" and `display` and check if the current letter is the same. If it is, you replace the underscore with the letter. If it isn't, you leave the underscore.

You'll find it useful to look at these functions that make it easy to deal with lists and other "iterables."

- [enumerate](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/): used here to loop over an index and element of an iterable at the same time.
- [zip](https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/): used here to loop over two iterables (`word` and `display`) at the same time.

```py
display = ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']

guess_letter = 'b'
word = 'baboon'

for index, (display_character, word_character) in enumerate(zip(display, word)):
    if guess_letter == word_character:
        display[index] = guess_letter

print(display)
```